# JComboBox no se llena JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Estaba revisando mi proyecto y me di cuenta que al momento de elegir el estudiante, año y las materias para agregar un registro de materia al "Colegio" el comboBox aparece vacio como en la imagen cuando clickeo sobre el comboBox para elegir el estudiante aparece vacio sin mas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego el codigo que utilizo para cargar el comboBox

```
public class CRUDRegistroMDialog {

// Declaracion de atributos para los botones, textFields, Labels, Objetos de
// comboBox y respectivo DatePicker Asi como sus labels para facilitar su
// guardado y manipulacion



@FXML
private ComboBox comboBoxEstudiante;

@FXML
private ComboBox comboBoxAnio;

@FXML
private static MainApp main;
ModelFactoryController modelFactoryController;

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    modelFactoryController = ModelFactoryController.getInstance();
    registros = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    listarEstudiantes();
    
    comboBoxAnio.getItems().addAll(// Aqui agregamos el aÃ±o de registro en
                                    // el comboBox
            "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024", "2025", "2026");
}

public void listarEstudiantes() {

    ArrayList<Estudiante> lista = modelFactoryController.getColegio().getListaEstudiantes();

    for (Iterator<Estudiante> iterator = lista.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Estudiante next = iterator.next();

        comboBoxEstudiante.getItems().addAll(next.getNombreEstudiante());
        
    }
    
}
```

¿Habra algo que hago mal?

Comment: ¿Verificaste que `lista` tiene datos? Haz un debug en ese punto, mostrando en pantalla sus elementos por ejemplo.

Comment: Si se guardan ya que al momento de abrir mi ventana de estudiantes aparecen alli en la tabla, Agregue un Syso() luego de guardar los estudiantes imprimiendo su nombre y si los guarda, Es extraño...

Comment: Tienes que hacer debug en `listarEstudiantes()` propiamente. ¿Lo has hecho ahí?

Comment: Hay un problema no entiendo muy bien la interfaz y el orden del Debug... :(

Comment: Dentro de `listarEstudiantes()`, y ahí dentro del `for`, puedes poner un `System.out.println(next.getNombreEstudiante());`, pues sería con esos supuestos datos con los que estarías llenando el objeto. Debes verificar lo que hay ahí.

Comment: Al parecer no se esta ejecutando el metodo si lo pongo en el initializable porque puse mi 'System.out.println(next.getNombreEstudiante());' y al momento de abrir la ventana de registro no imprime los nombres...Tratare de agregar un buton y asociar el metodo de listar los estudiantes y ver que tal.

Comment: Al vincular el metodo con un boton en la interfaz y presionarlo me arroja esto:       `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at admin.colegial.view.CRUDRegistroMDialog.listarEstudiantes(CRUDRegistroMDialog.java:292)`        Exactamente la linea 292 es :            `ArrayList<Estudiante> lista = modelFactoryController.getColegio().getListaEstudiantes();`   Solo que aun no comprendo porque el error alli.

Comment: Necesitas depurar tu código para determinar por qué hay una referencia nula en el mismo. Lo que presentas es una situación básica de depuración. Sin un contexto es difícil para nosotros decirte a qué se debe el error. Te recomiendo que hagas un pequeño esfuerzo por comprender tu propio código, de lo contrario tarde o temprano te encontrarás perdido en él, con la frustración que ello supone.

Answer (score 0):

Se debe agregar la etiqueta @FXML

```
 public class CRUDRegistroMDialog {

 @FXML
 public void initialize() {
 modelFactoryController = ModelFactoryController.getInstance();
 registros = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
 listarEstudiantes();

 comboBoxAnio.getItems().addAll(// Aqui agregamos el aÃ±o de registro en
                                // el comboBox
        "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024", "2025", "2026");
 }
```